# Debian loses harddisk on bootup 4 times and then boots. Why?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, linux-kernel, dma

Dmesg Dump:

http://paste.debian.net/44975
at time 32.832045

That error is delaying my boot process significantly.
Does anyone know what this is about?

Devices:
Maxtor IDE drive with new cable on primary master on a ASUS TUSL2-C board with Intel 815 Chipset and Pentium III Coppermine Processor.
Intel 82801BA IDE U100 controller.

Software:
Debian Wheezy on newest packages.
Kernel: Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1

Comment: Seriously, I am lost about that, crawled countless forums but nobody having really the same problem. The only one I could find with almost exact the same error posted two RUSSIAN LANGUAGE threads in the gentoo forum https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-947186-start-0.html and http://forum.oszone.net/post-2075655.html

Comment: I cant read russian, Google translator is so ultra unspecific at those threads that I cant make sense of it.

Comment: Did you get a message that says "Gave up waiting for root device..."? The Ubuntu forums thread mentions that as a possible symptom of this error as well.

Comment: Nope it wont give up for root device. I have encrypted root, so it waits infinitely because of the password prompt.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Ubuntu forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549579) (which may or may not apply, but since you're running Debian it's worth a shot), this can be fixed with these steps:

Follow the instructions in the last section of the first post, titled **Info about libata.force=... :**, to figure out your `libata` configuration.

> libata.force= [LIBATA] Force configurations. The format is comma
>   separated list of "[ID:]VAL" where ID is PORT[.DEVICE]. PORT and
>   DEVICE are decimal numbers matching port, link or device. Basically,
>   it matches the ATA ID string printed on console by libata. If the
>   whole ID part is omitted, the last PORT and DEVICE values are used. If
>   ID hasn't been specified yet, the configuration applies to all ports,
>   links and devices.
>
> If only DEVICE is omitted, the parameter applies to the port and all
>   links and devices behind it. DEVICE number of 0 either selects the
>   first device or the first fan-out link behind PMP device. It does not
>   select the host link. DEVICE number of 15 selects the host link and
>   device attached to it.
>
> The VAL specifies the configuration to force. As long as there's no
>   ambiguity shortcut notation is allowed. For example, both 1.5 and 1.5G
>   would work for 1.5Gbps. The following configurations can be forced.
>
> - Cable type: 40c, 80c, short40c, unk, ign or sata. Any ID with matching PORT is used.
> - SATA link speed limit: 1.5Gbps or 3.0Gbps.
> - Transfer mode: pio[0-7], mwdma[0-4] and udma[0-7]. udma[/][16,25,33,44,66,100,133] notation is also allowed.

Once you've done that, add the line you found to `grub.cfg`. For example, if the above steps gave you `libata.force=1:pio4`, add

```
libata.force=1:pio4
```

to the kernel line in grub. You can test this by pressing `e` at the Grub menu and adding the line manually to the kernel line. If it works, edit the `grub.cfg` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and edit the contents of this line to add the appropriate command:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="libata.force=1:pio4 quiet splash"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

I make no promises that this will work, since I don't have a system that's experiencing this error to test it on, but it looks like others have run into a similar problem, so maybe these steps will work for you.

Comment: That is propably a last resort option. Because: the hardware should definitely support DMA/100 mode and PIO4 only is terribly slow.

Comment: Despite that, forcing PIO4 works. But well, I want uDMA